# Postgres: is it posible to see how a Database View is constructed

Tags: postgresql, view

is it posible to see how a Database View is constructed in Postgres, to see wich query was used to create that view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `psql`:

```
\d+ the_view

--or

select definition from pg_views where viewname = 'the_view';
```